# Ms excel Table Creatibg table

Tags: microsoft-excel

In excel when I create a table with only 4 header titles which needs to be repeated again.
eg:day date name school
I want one more set with this like eg: day date name school day date name school
how can do this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to copy headings to an adjacent location.  To do this:

- Select the four cells.
- Hover your mouse over the bottom right-hand corner of the selection
  rectangle until it looks like a cross.
- Press and drag the mouse over the next four cells.
- When you release the mouse the cell headings should be copied to the
  new area.

As you drag the mouse, you should notice the proposed heading appear.  This helps if you are copying the heading set multiple times.